# Can I mix new and malloc on different redirection?

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator

Is this behaviour undefined where I am mixing both `new` and `malloc`?

```
int main()
{
  int ***arr = new int**[1];
  arr[0] = static_cast<int**>(malloc(sizeof(int**)));
  arr[0][0] = new int; 
  arr[0][0][0] = 1;

  //now, release memory using appropriate operator
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that though?

Comment: Just hypothetical. While reading one book I had the thought.

Comment: No, it's not undefined behavior. But it is a moot point. Modern C++ rarely requires a `new` or a `malloc` of anything, in the first place. Containers will do all the memory allocations for you, correctly, and without you having to worry about memory leaks.

Comment: I don't think it is exactly same question as duplicate. In the duplicate used variables are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You must call `delete[]`, `delete` and `free` accordingly later on. Be careful to not free something you got from `malloc` with `delete` etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this behaviour undefined where I am mixing both new and malloc?

There is no UB in the example.

You can do this, but there is no benefit.